# Creating a correlation matrix in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get a correlation matrix in SQL Server and my data is in a table the following way:

```
RptLOB1     RptLOB2   Correlation
AE          AE             1
Bail        AE            0.35
Commercial  Bail          0.25
Commercial  AE            0.15
```

...and so on.

I want to write a code so my output looks the following way:

```
            AE     Bail   Commercial
AE          1      0.35      0.15
Bail        0.35    1        0.25
Commercial  0.15   0.25       1
```

Order of the RptLOB doesn't matter as long as the order is the same from top to bottom and left to right on top.  I've been trying to find a way to approach this and I'm not quite sure what the best way is.  I was thinking using PIVOT but that will not output the RptLOB's on top (they will be considered as columns in the table).

EDIT:

This output is going to be inserted in another table like so:

```
col1             col2        col3                            col4        col5              

Generic
Company Inputs   Insurance   Stochastic Model Correlations   Exposure    Correlation Matrix
                 AE          Bail                            Commercial
AE               1           0.35                            0.15
Bail             0.35        1                               0.25
Commercial       0.15        0.25                            1
```

Comment: @OMGPonies   Well the only thing I could think of was pivoting the row values to create that top row but if I do that the row values become column headers and that's not what I want.  I'm not sure how to approach is so that doesn't happen and I can create the matrix...

Comment: I think this is going to be very hard using pure SQL. I suggest trying other tools, like R programming language.

Comment: If you don't want the columns to be column headers, you have a problem in that the data types don't match.

Comment: It wouldn't be a big deal to use R programming but I need to write a code for what I'm doing in SQL.  Would I be able to create a temp table with 46 columns (Number of RptLOB's I have) and pivot those RptLOB's to 1 row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `PIVOT` for this.  If you know the number of columns you have to transform, then you can use a static version:

```
select *
from 
(
  select RptLOB1 RptLOB1, RPTLOB2 RPTLOB2, Correlation
  from yourtable
  union all
  select RPTLOB2, RptLOB1, Correlation
  from yourtable
  union all
  select distinct RptLOB1, RptLOB1, 1.0
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(Correlation)
  for RPTLOB2 in ([AE], [Bail], [Commercial])
) p;
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f4fa/25)

If you have an unknown number of values to correlate, then you will want to use a dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ',' 
                      + quotename(RptLOB1)
                    from yourtable t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select RptLOB1, '+@colspivot+ '
     from 
     (
       select RptLOB1 RptLOB1, RPTLOB2 RPTLOB2, Correlation
       from yourtable
       union all
       select RPTLOB2, RptLOB1, Correlation
       from yourtable
       union all
       select distinct RptLOB1, RptLOB1, 1.0
       from yourtable
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        max(Correlation) 
        for RPTLOB2 in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f4fa/31)

Edit - based on your comments, if you want the column headers in another row, then you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot as  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsRow as  NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsConverted as  NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ',' 
                      + quotename(RptLOB1)
                    from yourtable t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsRow = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ', ''' 
                      + RptLOB1 + ''' as ' + RptLOB1
                    from yourtable t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsConverted
      = STUFF((SELECT distinct  ', CAST(' 
                + quotename(RptLOB1) 
                 + ' as varchar(50))'
                from yourtable t
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query 
  = 'select ''RptLOB1'' as RptLOB1, 
      '+ @colsRow + '
     union all 
     select RptLOB1, '+ @colsConverted+ '
     from 
     (
       select RptLOB1 RptLOB1, RPTLOB2 RPTLOB2, Correlation
       from yourtable
       union all
       select RPTLOB2, RptLOB1, Correlation
       from yourtable
       union all
       select distinct RptLOB1, RptLOB1, 1.0
       from yourtable
      ) x
      pivot
      (
        max(Correlation) 
        for RPTLOB2 in ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'

exec(@query)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f4fa/42)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way to display the column header (since it contains the other RptLOB's)?  This is eventually going to be done in dynamic sql.

Comment: @Kristina I am not sure what you mean by column header?  The column headers are retrieved in the dynamic sql when getting the value for `@colspivot`

Comment: @bluefeet  Eventually I'm going to write a dynamic sql statement so it spits out the whole correlation table and I want it to display the column names. Basically, this correlation matrix is going to be within another table.

Comment: @Kristina I don't understand what you are asking, can you post a sample of the final result you need?

Comment: @Kristina do you want the columns headers as a row in the table?

Comment: @bluefeet  yes that way those will show up in my correlation matrix display.

Comment: @bluefeet  Thank you so much for your help.  This has definitely helped me broaden my SQL horizons :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data is not complete enough.  So, enhance it with what you need:

```
with d as (
    select RptLOB1, RptLOB2, Correlation from t union all
    select RptLOB2, RptLOB1, Correlation from t union all
    select distinct RptLob1, RptLob1, 1.0 from t
)
select RptLOB1, RptLOB2, Corr
from d
pivot (max(correlation) for val in ('AE', 'Bail', 'Commercial')) as corr
```

If you don't know the names of all the values, then you will need dynamic SQL for the general case.