# How to create a correlation matrix or pivot based on values in a single field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create something like a correlation matrix in SQL server, looking at relationships between values in a single field.
The goal is something like this (I am restricted from sharing the actual fields and values):
If I had a list of purchases and products, can I output a matrix that shows how many individuals who purchased a given item *also* purchased another distinct item.
Example:
If this were my data:

```
[Account    Item        Amount
ID1 Bands       $20.00 
ID2 Bands       $20.00 
ID4 Foam Roller $40.00 
ID5 Foam Roller $40.00 
ID3 Shirt       $30.00 
ID1 Weights     $100.00 
ID4 Weights     $100.00 
ID1 Yoga Mat    $25.00 
ID2 Yoga Mat    $25.00 
ID4 Yoga Mat    $25.00 
ID5 Yoga Mat    $25.00][1]
```

I'd be looking to know how many accounts who bought a Yoga Mat also bought a Foam Roller, etc.
My desired output is something like this:

```
        [Bands  Foam Roller Shirt   Weights Yoga Mat
Bands       2               1   1
Foam Roller     2           1   1
Shirt                   1       
Weights     2                   2
Yoga Mat    2   2           1   4][1]
```

The business question is two-fold:

1. How many individuals making a purchase in one product category also purchased in another category?
2. What was the average spend in each category?

I've tried a pivot query but it isn't working. I'm sure I haven't structured it correctly. Does anyone have a suggestion or another thread I should look at? (I followed this one, but it isn't getting me there with only one field: [Creating a correlation matrix in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674600/creating-a-correlation-matrix-in-sql-server))

My result set from this is just a single row with the item names across the top and totals.

edited because my rows and columns were all run together; now pasted as images.
edited again due to feedback that the 'convert rows to columns' question is the same. Unfortunately, it isn't. I can get my rows into columns with values; I've done that.

What I'm really trying to do is see the crosstab or overlap of values in columns vs each other. eg How many Yoga Mat purchasers also bought a Foam Roller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: It doesn't. I worked through that one before asking.  Thank you though.

Comment: You will need to join the table to itself on `Account`, group by `First.Item` and `Second.Item`, sekect bot hof those plus a `COUNT(*)`, and then feed that to a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```sql
if object_id('tempdb..#t') is not null
    drop table #t
select LTRIM(rtrim(col1)) AS id, ltrim(rtrim(col2)) AS prod, stuff(ltrim(rtrim(col3)), 1, 1, '') AS price
into #t
from 

(
    VALUES  (N'ID1', 'Bands       ','$20.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID2', 'Bands       ','$20.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID4', 'Foam Roller ','$40.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID5', 'Foam Roller ','$40.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID3', 'Shirt       ','$30.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID1', 'Weights     ','$100.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID4', 'Weights     ','$100.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID1', 'Yoga Mat    ','$25.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID2', 'Yoga Mat    ','$25.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID4', 'Yoga Mat    ','$25.00 ')
    ,   (N'ID5', 'Yoga Mat    ','$25.00')
) t (col1, col2, col3)

;with cte as (
    select distinct prod from #t
    )
, cte2 AS (
select c.prod, t2.prod AS prod2, COUNT(*) AS cnt
from CTE c
inner join #t t
    ON  t.prod = c.prod
inner join #t t2
    ON  t2.id = t.id
GROUP BY c.prod, t2.prod
)
select prod, isnull(bands, 0) AS bands, isnull([foam roller],0) AS [foam roller], isnull(shirt, 0) AS shirt, isnull(Weights, 0) AS Weights, ISNULL([Yoga mat], 0) AS [Yoga Mat]
from cte2  c
pivot (MAX(c.cnt) for prod2 IN ([Bands], [Foam Roller], [Shirt],[Weights], [Yoga Mat])) p
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join the table to itself before feeding it to the `PIVOT`.

The pivot data value must be separate from the row and column values. In this case `Account` is used, but it could just as well have been `1 AS DummyValue`.

```
SELECT PVT.*
FROM (
    SELECT First.Account, First.Item, Second.Item AS OtherItem
    FROM @Data First
    JOIN @Data Second ON Second.Account = First.Account
) D
PIVOT (
  COUNT(Account)
  FOR OtherItem IN ([Bands], [Foam Roller], [Shirt], [Weights], [Yoga Mat])
) PVT
```

Result:

| Item | Bands | Foam Roller | Shirt | Weights | Yoga Mat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bands | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Foam Roller | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Shirt | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Weights | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| Yoga Mat | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 4 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9Rd2xxPi) for a demo.